# How to convert html file to chm format using c#?

Tags: c#, html, chm

I have thousands of HTML files and I want to convert these files to 
chm extension.

Please any way to convert HTML file to chm format using c#.

thanks.

Comment: Normally you just run a helpfile compiler.. what specifically are you having issues with?

Comment: i want do it programmatically using c# i don't know the way !

Comment: Thats what id still do.  Help compilers do it very efficiently.  You would need to read up a lot about chm to write your own

Comment: Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating help files (CHM) and help authoring has a learn curve. As @BugFinder mentioned in his comment - and you are warned again - you would need to read up a lot about CHM to write your own in C#.

Please note, HTMLHelp (HH) was shipped many years ago with IE4 and Windows 95. HTML Help is in maintenance mode, which means no new features are expected for either the runtime or the compiler. All mainstream development on HH has stopped. But it's still running under Windows10 and best help file format for Windows based applications.

You'll find many (and some expensive) tools for help authoring.

What I'd really recommend is Rob Chandler's shareware tool [FAR HTML](http://www.help-info.de/en/FAR/far.htm)
You can do anything with your prefered HTML-Editor outside and put FAR into your workflow. Or simple use your existing HTML files. It's a low priced tool and the wizards are great. Try it for your needs.

One tip - don't look at all the options of FAR HTML when starting.

1. Put your HTML files to structured subfolders of your project folder
   and note CHM is like a zipped web e.g.

   > welcome.htm
   >   design.css
   >   First_Steps\download.htm
   >   First_Steps\starting_program.htm
   >   How_to_extend\extend_menu.htm
   >   How_to_extend\power_function.htm
   >   images\gui_screenshot.jpg
2. Drag and drop these files to FAR HTML or open from the wizard Dialog in your working root folder
3. Start the wizard for HTMLHelp 1.x see main menu: Authoring > Help Wizard
4. Follow the Wizard steps
5. Ready ..

[image]